# How to use a CONCAT statement with a CASE statement in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, case, concatenation

Is it possible to use CONCAT with a CASE statement in BigQuery? If so, how?

When we try this code, it gives the error below:

```
SELECT 

CONCAT(
     "Age:",
     CASE WHEN Age IS null THEN "" ELSE Age END AS Age
) AS AgeString

FROM [our table]
```

> Error: Encountered " "AS" "AS "" at line 5, column 49. Was expecting:
>   ")" ...

Comment: Does it work if you use standard SQL instead? The Cloud Console UI defaults to standard SQL, as do most of the client libraries.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard That gives, "Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AS at [5:44]"

Comment: There's your problem :) You can't put an alias inside `CONCAT`.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard That worked. Do you want to write that as an answer or prefer I do?

Comment: Added an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
SELECT 

CONCAT(
     "Age:",
     CASE WHEN Age IS null THEN "" ELSE Age END AS Age  -- <- this alias
) AS AgeString

FROM [our table]
```

Since you can't put an alias inside an expression, this query returns an error using either legacy or standard SQL. The fix is to remove the alias:

```
SELECT 

CONCAT(
     "Age:",
     CASE WHEN Age IS null THEN "" ELSE Age END
) AS AgeString

FROM [our table]
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative - if for some reason that alias is "important" for you for example from documenting prospective and/or making code more verbose/descriptive - you can wrap up CASE with SELECT as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT CONCAT(
  "Age:",
  (SELECT CASE WHEN Age IS NULL THEN "" ELSE Age END AS Age)
) AS AgeString
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```